# AngularJs - Getting value of ng-src attribute in controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, ng-image-compress

I am working on browse and upload image functionality in my AngularJs application. I am using ng-image-compress for compressing image. I need to access a value of ng-src attribute in my controller whenever user selects an image from browse file dialog.

```
<input id="File1" type="file" accept="image/*" image="image1" ng-image-compress ng-model="image2" 
        resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" 
        onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadPhoto()" />
<br /><br />
<img ng-src="{{image1.compressed.dataURL}}" class="thumb" />
```

using above code, when I selects image, uploadPhoto() method called and selected image displays properly in img tag but I want to access ng-src value OR {{image1.compressed.dataURL}} in uploadPhoto() method.

NOTE :

```
 <button ng-click="uploadPicture(image1.compressed.dataURL)">Submit</button>
```

If I try this, I got compressed dataUrl in uploadPicture() but I don't want this type of processing.  please suggest appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use plain JS `onchange` event, you are out of the controller scope, that is why you have to call `angular.element(this).scope()` to get back to the scope and execute `uploadPhoto()` method.

Try to use Angular JS's [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) method:

```
<input id="File1" 
       type="file" 
       accept="image/*" 
       image="image1" 
       ng-image-compress 
       ng-model="image2" 
       resize-max-height="800" 
       resize-max-width="800" 
       resize-quality="0.7" 
       resize-type="image/jpg" 
       ng-change="uploadPhoto()" />
<br /><br />
<img ng-src="{{image1.compressed.dataURL}}" class="thumb" />
```

Now you should be able to access `$scope.image1.compressed.dataURL` within your controller or service.

If you MUST stay with JS solution using 'scope()' function, try to pass needed info as argument to `uploadPhoto()` function (if possible). Something like:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadPhoto(angular.element(this).scope().image1.compressed.dataURL)"
```

or using jQUery:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadPhoto(angular.element(this).next('img').attr('src'))"
```

**UPDATE**

here is solution using `$scope.$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('image1.compressed.dataURL', function(nVal) {
  if (nVal) {
    console.log('image1.compressed.dataURL', nVal);
  }
});
```

here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ArdhF6rPtREMCAzt7Eec?p=preview

in the plunker I populate another scope variable and use it on HTML

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already try both of suggestions. ng-change not fired in case input type = file that’s why I used plain JS onchange() event. `onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadPhoto(angular.‌​element(this).scope(‌​).image1.compressed.‌​dataURL)"` results in  **Uncaught TypeError “Cannot read property 'compressed' of undefined”**

If I use only `onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadPhoto(angular.‌​element(this).scope(‌​).image1)"` then I got undefined value for image1. 

I don't understand what the thing I am missing?

Comment: did you try to pass `angular.element(this).next('img').attr('src')`?

Comment: Hi Andriy, I tries with this and also several possible ways. 
`angular.element(this).next('img').attr('src')` as well as `angular.element(this).next('img').attr('ng-src')` gived me undefined value in controller.

Using `angular.element('img')` gives me img tag details excluding src value as 
<img class=​"thumb ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model=​"imgCompressUrl">​.

Is there someway to attach ng-src to ng-model or to scope variable and access that variable in controller.

Comment: I see you have ` ng-model=​"imgCompressUrl"`, did you also try to access angular.element(this).scope().imgCompressUrl?

Comment: I updated my answer and added plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/ArdhF6rPtREMCAzt7Eec?p=preview) where I use `$scope.$watch` on `image1.compressed.dataURL`

Comment: Hi Andriy, thank you so much for your efforts on this. Finally my issue is resolved by using `$scope.$watch` on `image1.compressed.dataURL`. This is exactly the solution I am looking for. Thanks again. Have a nice day.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :) Have a nice day too!